# Get text from text field on Table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a **custom cell** with a `UITextField` . Where I should set the `delegate`, in the custom cell class or in the view's class ?

I was trying to do this in both, but no results. I set the delegate from storyboard.

Here is what I did:

```
-(void)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        return;
    }

    UIAlertView *helloEarthInputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                         initWithTitle:@"Name!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", textField.text]
                                         delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [helloEarthInputAlert show];

}
```

But this part is working if i put this cell.noteTextField.delegate=self :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y-30, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the delegate in the custom cell's class. But do not forget to implement the protocols

```
// MyCell.h

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
// ...

// MyCell.m

-(void)autoconfigureCell // a method I added to configure cell, but also can do in "-(void)layoutSubviews"
{
    // ...
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    // ...
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField // <-- BOOL
{
    // do stuff

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the delegate in your ViewController, it has to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and to know what textfield is calling the delegate methods, you can do something like this:

```
-(void)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint textFieldPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldPosition];
    ...
}
```